# How to populate a TableView in QML with an class in C++

Tags: c++, qt, listview, delegates, qml

I am new to Qt and have been pulling my hair out for hours on how to do this. I have found a few examples related to the topic but I just don't fully understand.

I need to populate a ListView with a class that I have created. I think I need to use a delegate but any example I see of ListView delegates are all made with the list in C++, so I don't know how to reference the list if its in qml, or they are not very detailed. I have a general idea of how a simple delegate works but I don't know or understand how to implement one with a ListView.

I pretty sure that the class I want to set as my model needs to inherit from QAbstractListModel, but any farther then that, I'm lost.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    id: main_window
    ...

    Column {
        id: column
    ...
        }
    }

    Column {
        id: column1
        ....

        Row {
            id: row
            ....
        }

        Row {
            id: row1
            ....

            TableView {
                id:data_table
                objectName: data_table
                TableViewColumn {
                    role: "ip"
                    title: "Source IP"
                }
                TableViewColumn {
                    role: "type"
                    title: "Attack Type"
                }
                TableViewColumn {
                    role: "rate"
                    title: "Rate (P/sec)"
                }
                TableViewColumn {
                    role: "city"
                    title: "City"
                }
                TableViewColumn {
                    role: "country"
                    title: "County"
                    width: row1.width * 0.125
                }
                TableViewColumn {
                    role: "isp"
                    title: "ISP"
                }
                model: list_model 
            }
       }
  }
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <source_data.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QList<QObject> model;

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}
```

source_data.h

```
#include <QString>
#include <QAbstractListModel>

class Source_Data : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString ip READ ip WRITE setIp)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString type READ type WRITE setType)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString rate READ rate WRITE setRate)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString city READ city WRITE setCity)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString country READ country WRITE setCountry)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString isp READ isp WRITE setIsp)

public:
    QString ip() const;
    QString type() const;
    QString rate() const;
    QString city() const;
    QString country() const;
    QString isp() const;

    void setIp(const QString & ip);
    void setType(const QString & type);
    void setRate(const QString & rate);
    void setCity(const QString & city);
    void setCountry(const QString & country);
    void setIsp(const QString & isp);

private:
    QString m_ip;
    QString m_type;
    QString m_rate;
    QString m_city;
    QString m_country;
    QString m_isp;
};
```

Comment: QTableView is not part of QML, but Qt Widgets. You should use `TableView` item. See [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#subclassing) documentation. You should to implement virtual methods to provide your data.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to do provide a list of `Source_Data` in c++ so you can display it in QML in a `ListView`/`TableView` (one row per `Source_Data`)?

Comment: Read Qt documentation, it has a complete part titled "Using C++ Models with Qt Quick Views" : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html

Comment: Your problem is actually not related to the specific type of the view. You should explore how to create a data model in C++. You might be happy to find the *Qt QML Tricks*-library by T. Boutroue with the `QQmlObjectListModel` here: http://gitlab.unique-conception.org/qt-libraries/lib-qt-qml-tricks (I am not affiliated with that site!)